# a special character "\u9d28"(鴨) in SourceHanSerifTC-Light cannot show in PDF

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

the Code is in followings

```
        PdfWriter dest = new PdfWriter("o.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(dest);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        string chFontPath = "c:\\windows\\fonts\\SourceHanSerifTC-Light.otf";
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(chFontPath, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, false);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.SetFont(font);
        p.Add(new Text("\u9d28"));            
        document.Add(p);
        document.Close();
```

This code "\u9d28"'鴨' cannot be shown.

However, others character is fine. and if the character "\u9d28"鴨 combines with this character "\u9d30"鴰. it also works.

```
        p.Add(new Text("\u9d28\u9d30"));
```

I also test with Itextsharp that still not lucky. 
I have tested with Word in the SourceHanSerifTC font, everything is fine.

```
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A7);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\rick.DOMAIN10\Desktop\新增資料夾 (3)\ChunkPhraseParagraph.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();

        //設定中文字體
        string chFontPath = "c:\\windows\\fonts\\SourceHanSerifTC-Light.otf";                        
        BaseFont chBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(chFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        iTextSharp.text.Font chFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(chBaseFont, 12);
        Phrase simplePhr1 = new Phrase("鴨", chFont);
        Phrase simplePhr1 = new Phrase("\u928", chFont);
        iTextSharp.text.Paragraph simplePara = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph();
        simplePara.Add(simplePhr1);

        doc.Add(simplePara);

        doc.Close();
```

How could I print out this character with Itext?

Comment: Can you generate a PDF with that character and upload it somewhere, so we can take a closer look?

Comment: Indeed, only in combinations with certain other glyphs the \u9d28 glyph of that font can be used, also if using iText 7 for Java. It depends on the font, though, there is no problem when using e.g. SourceHanSerifTC-Regular.otf.

Comment: Actually, all other fonts and characters are fine. Only this character in this font has this problem as I known. And, only this combination can show this character. Here is the [pdf output](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F1WjLq3OOWBFgjcMbjubC87-3fBormOf?usp=sharing)

Comment: The error message is "Cannot extract the embedded font 'LLLLLL+SourceHanSerifTC-Light-Identity-H'. Some characters may not display or print correctly."  However, the setup of the font is not embedded.